# How to turn 1-bit 64x6x bitmap image into an array of ones and zeroes?

Tags: bash, bitmap

I'm looking to do this in Bash, if possible. The bitmap image in question is 64x64, and only contains black and white pixels, nothing in between. I'm trying to write a script in bash that can somehow read the image, and return either a 1 for white, and a 0 for black, for each pixel in the image. So, the output would look something like this:

```
01001001010001010101010...
```

Can this be done in Bash? If so, can some example code be given?

Comment: That can easily be done through Python and Numpy. Will it help if I give you a python script for it?
Sorry no experience with bash.

Comment: Yes, a python script would work great!

Comment: Is the script ready yet?

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) + [netpbm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/netpbm.1.html) as follows:

```
convert my.png -monochrome pnm:-|pnmtoplainpnm|tail -n+4|tr -d ' \n'
```

If you do not have `netpbm` available on your platform for whatever reason:

```
convert my.png -monochrome -compress none pnm:-|sed '1,2d;s/255/1/g'|tr -d ' \n'
```

I use "png" as an input here, but ImageMagick will accept a wide range of input bitmap formats:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

**Test**

`my.png`

[image]

```
%convert my.png -monochrome -compress none pnm:-|sed '1,2d;s/255/1/g'|tr -d ' \n'\
|fold -16

0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0001111111111100
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000010000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

Comment: How would I go about replacing those ones and zeroes with a much longer string? For example: the 0 would be replaced with "this-is-white", and the 1 would be replaced with "this-is-black". I tried fiddling with the sed portion of it, but I couldn't get it to change from ones and zeroes.

Comment: @AfterHours Try this: `sed '1,2d;s/255/this-is-white/g;s/0/this-is-black/g;'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'/home/Bitmapfont.png')
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

grey_img[grey_img !=255] = 0
grey_img[grey_img ==255] = 1

print grey_img
```

Let me know it any change is required :)